# Certificate confusion

Tags: ssl, certificate, keystore, truststore

i have some problem with certificate. I have a web application work on tomcat 8 web server.
Connector of tomcat is:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" maxThreads="150"
              SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"
                keystoreFile="/usr/share/tomcat8/lib/keystoreMPS.jks"
                keystorePass="testnoe"
                sslProtocol="TLS"  />
```

My client says : "hey go here (domain name), take my public key, importo in your trustsore and it's done"

I use this command to see the certificate:

```
openssl s_client -connect (domain name):443
```

take the BEGIN CERTIFICATE and END CERTIFICATE, imported on my truststore and nothing. 
I must do a csr and private key?
Can someone make me understand please? i'm reading everything but i have a lot of confusion.

Comment: Your question is confusing too and not well written. If I understand, you want to add a server's certificate into a client's truststore. There are many tutorials for that once you have the certificate (your openssl is ok) : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/rstep2.html

Comment: Sorry my english, yes you understand. So with that open ssl i copy the BEGIN CERTIFICATE and END CERTIFICATE i i have the public key so right and now i can import in my truststore?

Comment: you copy the certificate including these 2 lines (BEGIN .. END) to a file, and you import this file with keytool as explained in the tutorial.

Comment: i tried but nothing, but if i use openssl s_client -CApath ~/.cert/mail.nixcraft.net/ -connect mail.nixcraft.net:443 to see if the certificate is working and it's ok

Comment: if your client is in Java, use this system property then we see what's happening -Djavax.net.debug=ssl